# Int object is not callable when calling an object within a class

Tags: python, class, object, python-turtle

I am making a program that has 2 spaceships battle. It is working so far but when we call the attack function we get this error:

```
"TypeError: 'int' object is not callable on line 54"
```

I spent a while debugging but I can't figure out where it went wrong. Here is the code: Please provide some suggestions to make it work

```
import turtle
import time
import random
drawer = turtle.Turtle()
drawer.shape("square")
drawer.speed(0)
attacker = turtle.Turtle()
attacker.shape("square")
attacker.speed(0.5)
attacker.penup()

color1 = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
color2 = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))

class spaceship:
  def __init__(self,name,health,attack,sheild,x,y):
    self.name = name
    self.health = health
    self.attack = attack
    self.sheild = sheild
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  def draw_spaceship(self, color):
    drawer.color(color)
    drawer.penup()
    drawer.goto(self.x, self.y)
    drawer.begin_fill()
    for i in range(0,4):
      drawer.forward(100)
      drawer.right(90)
    drawer.end_fill()
  def attack(self, color, enemy_name):
    attacker.goto(self.x, self.y)
    attacker.goto(enemy_name.x, enemy_name.y)
    attacker.color(color)
    where_attack = random.randrange(0,2)
    if where_attack == 1:
      where_attack = "health"
      enemy_name.health -= self.attack
    else:
      where_attack = "sheild"
      enemy_name.sheild -= self.attack
    print(self.name,"is attacking the",where_attack,"of",enemy_name.name+".")
    print("Now",enemy_name.name,"has",enemy_name.health,"health.")

# draws spaceships
Noob = spaceship("Noob",random.randrange(100,500),random.randrange(10,200),random.randrange(10,200),-250,50)
Noob.draw_spaceship(color1)

Pro = spaceship("Pro",random.randrange(100,1000),random.randrange(100,500),random.randrange(10,200),100,50)
Pro.draw_spaceship(color2)

drawer.forward(2000)

Pro.attack(color1, Noob)
```

Comment: Please include **all the info** from the exception. Which line is line 54?

Comment: The attribute `self.attack = attack` in `__init__` hides the method with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring the `spaceship`'s attribute (variable) `attack` the same as its method `attack()`.
Since `Pro` is an instance of `spaceship`, when you call `Pro.attack()` at the end of your script you are actually trying to call its attribute of type *int*.

Try changing the method's name to something else

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename the method "attack" then try again. Seems like an attribute and a method are called with the same name.